# Re-use the face recognition library in lightroom on another PC?

Tags: lightroom, face-detection

I have a rather large database of faces/names, created in Lightroom using the automatic face recognition. Is there a way to export some of those faces, to be reused in another installation of Lightroom (so that the other users do not have to import all my pictures)?

Answer (score 1):

The face recognition is stored somewhere in the LR catalog, which is just regular SQLite database.
[Here is a related question on editing the LR catalog database](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/93172/9161).

In theory you could, backup the original catalog, find the right table(s) in the catalog database, isolate the relevant rows and copy them over to the new database.

However, there's no database documentation and the tables refer to each other through various columns. All these references should match, otherwise the catalog is seen as corrupt.

If you manage to do this successfully, please share the method and documentation here :)