# Lightroom CC relationship between People and pictures

Tags: lightroom, face-detection, creative-commons

Is there a way to retrieve the database of associations between one person and all the tagged pictures?

Both mac Photos and Windows Photos have an unencrypted sqlite database from where it is easy to query all the photos of one person.

Yet I can't figure this out for Lightroom CC.

Comment: "*retrieve the database of associations*" ?  Retrieve or access ?  Keyword search is not what you need ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find Lightroom database documentation?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/93172/where-can-i-find-lightroom-database-documentation)

Comment: i think the link refers to LR classic, not LR CC, so no.

Comment: Uh... aren't Lightroom catalogs also unencrypted sqlite databases?

Comment: @inkista, so? If you can open the Lightroom catalog and figure out the structure so as to extract the people/picture relationships, then please click 'answer the question', I'll be more than happy. I am under the impression that part of the data in lr cc is stored in the cloud, but there is not even an lr cc api to query it :( maybe I'm wrong and it's all in the catalog.